# Возврат массива из функции Си

Tags: c, массивы

Необходимо реверснуть массив (функция revers), но при попытке компиляции пишет:

```
main.c:39:16: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[12]' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void revers(int*)'
revers(&bin);
```

Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void revers(int *bin)
{
    int temp, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12 / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = bin[i];
        bin[i] = bin[12 - i - 1];
        bin[12 - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}

int *binary_system(int number)
{
    int bin[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        bin[i] = 0;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            bin[i] = 0;
            number /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            bin[i] = 1;
            number /= 2;
        }
        i++;
    }
    revers(&bin);
    return bin;
}

void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k)
{
    int *nbin, *kbin;
    nbin = binary_system(n);
    kbin = binary_system(k);
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Главное, что вы пытаетесь возвратить адрес локальной переменной, а это прямая дорога к UB...

Comment: Но ведь нельзя вернуть массив, поэтому приходится передавать адрес. И что такое UB?

Comment: Значит, надо создавать массив вне функции и передавать его в нее, как аргумент. Или обернуть его в структуру. По окончании функции массив исчезает, и им нельзя пользоваться - это приводит к неопределенному поведению (undefined behavior, UB).

Comment: В следующий раз помещайте код прямо в вопрос. Мы поможем отформатировать.